# Program freezing if function is present after the freezing point

Tags: c++, for-loop, cin

When function `analiza()` isn't commented, my program shows both messages in `input()` function. (`przed`, `po`), But, if I uncomment the `analiza()` after `input()`, it breaks. I tried cleaning buffers, diffrent libraries ect. NOTHING helped. Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

unsigned int liczba_osob, liczba_klapek, przeszli = 0;
unsigned long long osoby[200000], klapki[200000], minimum;
bool do_uzycia[200000]{0};

unsigned long long greatest();
bool czy_mozliwe(unsigned int osoba);
void input();
void analiza();

int main()
{
    input();
  analiza();
    return 0;
}

unsigned long long greatest()
{
    unsigned long long maxrn = klapki[0];
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < liczba_klapek; i++)
        if (klapki[i] > maxrn)
            maxrn = klapki[i];
    return maxrn;
}

bool czy_mozliwe(unsigned int osoba)
{
    if (osoby[osoba] >= minimum)
        return 1;
    unsigned long long maximim = greatest();
    if (osoby[osoba] + maximim < minimum)
        return 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < liczba_klapek; i++)
    {
        if (osoby[osoba] + klapki[i] >= minimum && !do_uzycia[i])
        {
            do_uzycia[i] = 1;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
void input()
{
    cin >> liczba_osob;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < liczba_osob; i++)
        cin >> osoby[i];

    cin >> liczba_klapek;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < liczba_klapek; i++)
        cin >> klapki[i];
cout<<"przed";
    cin >> minimum;
    cout<<"po";
}
void analiza()
{
     for (unsigned int i = 0; i < liczba_osob; i++)
        if (czy_mozliwe(i))
            przeszli++;
    cout << przeszli;
}
```

So, the problem rn is with input:

```
200000
10 20 30... (and 199997 times more)
200000
10 20 30... (and 199997 more)
2500000
```

so max input due to arrays being 200000 long. Program freezes in the `input()` after `cout<<"przed";`. It doesn't get input to the minimum variable. If I remove call to `analiza()` in `int main()`, the problem doesn't occurr.

Here's the input file that makes the problem [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OZjh7XnmwAStP_bTpm7sCaFtMnnGP4nX/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: do you input anything after before is printed?

Comment: @PeterTrencansky yes.

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: @Quimby. It is a compilable and runnable version. The biggest problem is that we not know at all, what sahll be achieved. And I can only guess some parts, because of the non English variable names.

Comment: @StanisławNowak. You need to explain more. I can compile and run the program. It does something. But I do not know, what it should do. Can you explain, what you want to achieve.

Comment: I assume that in your sample input the numbers on the second and fourth lines are in increasing order. If you change the sequence of numbers in the input in certain ways, the number that is printed at the end can be reduced. Is that the desired behavior? It seems the main problem here is an inefficient algorithm, but if it really is dependent on the sequence of the input it will be harder to optimize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the given input, your function `analiza` makes 200000 = 2 * 10^5 calls to the function `czy_mozliwe`. That function in turn calls `greatest`, which makes 2 * 10^5 iterations of a loop with a comparison in each iteration, and then `czy_mozliwe` proceeds to run its own loop with 2 * 10^5 iterations.

So in order to finish executing `analiza`, the computer needs to execute 4 * 10^10 iterations of the loop in `greatest` and 4 * 10^10 iterations of the loop in `czy_mozliwe`.

That might take a long time.

Meanwhile the output you queued up with `cout<<"po";` may just be waiting in a buffer. You haven't seen it come out because you didn't flush the buffer when you wrote it.
Try `cout<<"po"<<std::endl;` instead.

Then you might think about how you can write your program so it doesn't require so many iterations of its inner loops.